# Spring Boot delete multiple rows from two entities JHipster

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I am using Spring Boot for back-end in my project. In function `deleteDoctor`, I want to delete doctor by id from table `doctor`, and at the same time I want to delete associated `user` in `user` table who has the login of the `doctor`.

However, the flow does not work, code reference below:

```
@DeleteMapping("/doctor/{id}")
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteDoctor(@PathVariable String id,
                                         @RequestBody Doctor doctor) {
  log.debug("REST request to delete Doctor : {}", id);
  doctorRepository.delete(id);

  userRepository.findOneByLogin(doctor.getLogin()).
    ifPresent(user -> {
      userRepository.delete(user);
      log.debug("Deleted User: {}", user);
    });

  return ResponseEntity.ok()
    .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(ENTITY_NAME, id.toString())).build();
}
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an exception? If so stack trace, please.

Answer (score 0):

Annotate `deleteDoctor()` method with `@Transactional` or better: move that code down to a service method with `@Transactional`